# Using miglayout with netbeans

Tags: java, ide, netbeans, installation, miglayout

I'm trying to use miglayout within the netbeans IDE. Ive placed the miglayout files in the right place and then imported using:

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

at the top of my file but it states that "package net.miginfocom.swing does not exist"

Any ideas on how I can get miglayout working withing netbeans? Any way possible?

Thanks in advance, 
Lee

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you haven't added the miglayout library (jar files you downloaded from the miglayout website) to your [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29). Right click on your project, select properties, select libraries and hit "add jar", select the downloaded files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the jar file into your classpath. That's in the "properties" settings for your project.